# jQuery: triggering paste?

Tags: javascript, jquery, paste

Is there any way to trigger a paste in jQuery?

Or maybe a broader question: is there any cross-browser way to trigger a paste with Javascript at all?

Comment: would you want any site to gather any data from your clipboard?

Comment: @fazo - "would you want" is not a fair response to this type of question.  All kinds of terrible behaviors have been technically possible with HTML, JS and the DOM at one time or another (and not quickly patched).  Major browsers only blocked this one recently, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394890/css-javascript-hacking-detect-visited-styling-on-a-link-without-checking-it-d . Of course in this case the answer is "no, it's not technically possible", but that's separate from the question of whether it's a good practice.

Comment: @Ben you are right, but my point rather was 'do you expect your browser to provide potentially sensitive data to gather by webservers'. and unfortunately people are at risk with ie and flash

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27614719/1922144

Comment: Triggering a paste event is not the same thing as retrieving the contents of the clipboard.  JavaScript has an 'onPaste' event that can be triggered.

Answer (score 8):

Getting data from the user's clipboard is a pretty big security risk (for the user).  Zero Clipboard will get you part of the way there (requires Flash), although it will only let you mimic paste using what you've copied using their library.

http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/

You won't find a cross-browser JavaScript or jQuery only solution, though.

Comment: "You won't find a cross-browser JavaScript or jQuery only solution, though." For good reason, as mentioned, this is a HUGE security issue and as a user I hate it. As a developer, I realize users hate it, therefore I don't do it.

Comment: Unfortunately there are situations that for usability client's will request such behavior. Say you have a field divided into 3 inputs (eg. a phone number) and someone wants to be able to just paste the full phone number into the fields. How would you do that? Well you could attach to the paste event into the first input (using jquery) but that would only work if you didn't limit the input of the first field, but then your sacrificing you field restrictions for the sake of additional functionality. Unfortunately, I've had to implement some weighty solutions to get around this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot trigger a cut, copy or paste programmatically in JavaScript and still maintain cross browser support. These actions can only come from the user.

Comment: This is no longer relevant, Cut and Copy have been implemented in all evergreen browsers.