# How to trigger a function, after right click paste

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to trigger function after right click paste option.
below code I tried but its not work for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#textA').on('paste',function(){ 

      //something...

   });

});
```

What is the best way to trigger right click paste event?

Comment: actually ur code will work...can u give as fiddle code?

Comment: I used Jquery old version thatz why it not worked correctly.It works with jQuery newer version. thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('paste',function(){ 

   //your logic   

   });
```

Comment: Thambi albert please explain your answer then only we ca understand and put postive votes for you

Comment: I think its self explanatory

Comment: @Hsakarp: Then you can surely explain why this is "best way to trigger right click paste event" please? (I guess the OP means "listen to the paste event"). Why is better than what the OP has?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('paste', function(e){
    if(e.clipboardData.types.indexOf('text/html') > -1){
        processDataFromClipboard(e.clipboardData.getData('text/html'));
        e.preventDefault();

        ...
    }
});
```

### Further:

- [Clipboard API and events](http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#events)