# Javascript Find The Colour Of Link

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, anchor

So the issue I'm having basically comes down, I have a list of external websites in HTML (as seen below).

```
<a id="listitem0" href="http://google.com.au/">http://google.com.au/</a><br />
<a id="listitem1" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">http://stackoverflow.com/</a><br />
<a id="listitem2" href="http://kbbdigital.com.au/">http://kbbdigital.com.au/</a><br />
<a id="listitem3" href="http://netreach.com.au/">http://netreach.com.au/</a><br />
```

And some of them I have visited & others I haven't, so I have CSS styling to help identify the visited vs not visited (as seen below).

```
<style type="text/css">
    a {
    color:#999999;
    background-color:#000;
}

a:visited {
    color:#00FF00;
    background-color:#30F;
}
</style>
```

Visually I can see which websites have & haven't been visited, but when I run a basic javascript line it can't pick up the colour of the text or the background colour (code below), it just provides blank output.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
alert(document.getElementById("listitem0").style.backgroundColor);
alert(document.getElementById("listitem0").style.color);
</script>
```

Does anyone know why it can't pick up the colour of the text based on the CSS set earlier? And is there solution to get this?

I'm using Firefox 27.0.1 to run these tests, but have tried other browsers as well, but receive the same issue.

Comment: you want to learn about getComputedStyle. `getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue("color")` -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle

Comment: what is `a#`? never did like this before in css.. :/

Comment: `element.style` will only get inline styles.

Comment: sidenote: this should be a and a:visited (with no sharps)

Comment: I should've mentioned that I did try this. It however does not return correct results either.

The a# was an accident, edited now to get rid of the #.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Then this should also be of interest: [privacy-related changes coming to CSS :visited](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/). From 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The detection of visited links is disabled as a privacy measure. And thanks for that.

Ref. [privacy-related changes coming to CSS :visited](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/)

In short, it can't be done. That said, there might be hacks, but those would most likely quickly be patched and as a result being unreliable.

From what I read, this is implemented in most browsers.

---

As an example of how one could hack the history is using timing attacks. That is in short:

1. You want to know if user has visited `aleister_crowley.com`
2. You find an item which all users would have cached, lets say `aleister_crowley.com/profile.jpg`
3. You add a script to load this picture in your site, and time how long it takes.

If user has visited the page the image would load quickly due to caching in the users browser. As such you can estimate the user has, in fact, visited that page.

[More in this paper](http://sip.cs.princeton.edu/pub/webtiming.pdf).

---

Then of course, this would be a case were your site has flipped to the dark side.

Comment: Ok thanks. I thought this might've been the case, but thought I'd put it out there to everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Make following changes to CSS,

```
a {                        // element selector will select all `a` elements in document
    color:#999999;
    background-color:#000;
}
a:visited {
    color:#00FF00;
    background-color:#30F;
}
```

And do following,

```
var element = document.getElementById("listitem0");
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element), // will return you CSSStyleDeclaration { }. Style object
    color = style.getPropertyValue('color'), // return property value
    background = style.getPropertyValue('background-Color');

console.log(color, background);
```

### <kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8MVeV/)</kbd>

Comment: Yep, should've mentioned that I did try this. It however does not return correct results either.

Comment: @chaff91 what are you getting?

Comment: That the color is rgb(0, 0, 0) & the background color is rgb(153, 153, 153) on a link I have visited (so not even close).

Comment: This is a Security/Privacy blocking. It will work on anything but anchors. It used to work, but tat is a long time ago.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394890/css-javascript-hacking-detect-visited-styling-on-a-link-without-checking-it @user13500

Answer (score 2):

Here it is,

```
element = document.getElementById("listitem0");
alert(window.getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue("background-color")); 
alert(window.getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue("color"));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvijayakumar/afCcz/)**

Answer (score 1):

Below code to find the color of link with cross browser solution.

```
var link = document.getElementById('listitem0');  // Find element

// Cross Browser Solution to get the color of link
var getStyle = function(el, cssProperty){
    if(typeof getComputedStyle !== 'undefined'){
        return window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue(cssProperty);
    } else {
        // This will work in legacy browsers(IE8 and below)
        return el.currentStyle[cssProperty];
    }
}

var colorName = getStyle(link, 'color');
alert(colorName)
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/87cmu/1/)

Comment: You can make your answer better by providing an **explanation** of the solution.

Comment: I get you're answer (I'm a developer) & I should've mentioned that I did try this (well not exactly with that function). It however does not return correct results either.

Comment: dear downvoter, it would be great if you explain the reason behind down voting.

Answer (score 0):

The style property gives you the value that is set inline, in the HTML tag element's `style` property.
In your case you use CSS styling, so you need to use the `getComputedStyle` API:
`window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('listitem0')).color`

Answer (score 0):

First you seem to have to '#' after you CSS a styles. Remove those. Second, I'm not sure what the problem is with the regular js. Works with jQuery.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkQ3Y/)

```
alert($('#listitem0').css('background-color'));
alert($('#listitem0').css('color'));
```

Comment: Just because he didn't mention it doesn't mean it's not an available option. I checked OP's profile and he works for a website dev company, therefore I assume he knows what jQuery is. With that said, since I didn't know why the js wasn't working, I thought I'd mention that it could be done with jQuery. Sure the js method will load probably work faster, but nonetheless my jquery method works too.

Comment: With all due respect to jQuery, it is not only about loading faster...but also about choice...if you quick duck-duck-go(or google...choice is yours!), you can find several (not as popular...which doesn't necessarily mean not equally good) jQuery alternatives.

Comment: Oh for sure, jQuery is not the only, or the best option, it was just the only other option I could offer. For the purposes of the OP's question, some simple js works just fine, especially if that's all the script he's adding to the page. Personally, if I was already using jQuery on the page, I would most likely keep using jQuery to do what he's trying to do.... if it made sense and it wasn't unnecessary. For other purposes tho, you're def right, there's plenty of other options. I've recently found that AngularJS is actually pretty sweet.