# Facebook Application - how to hide URL parameters?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, url, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a little Facebook application and what makes me a bit disturbed is, that all information is possible to see in URL (like filename, GET parameter).

Is there any way, how could I hide them? Maybe with using Javascript/AJAX or is there any else/better feature to achieve that?

Comment: And what “disturbs” you about that? You have heard the phrase, that there is no such thing as “Security by Obscurity”, haven’t you …?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hide them from someone who really wants to see them.

With some of the debugging tools available, it is possible to watch all network traffic exactly as it happens.

You can hide them *from a 3rd party watcher* by using `SSL` *(https://)* but you can't hide it from the local machine.

Comment: Actually, I am using SSL. But how can I hide it? Could you give me some example/tip/link for tutorial?

Comment: See this more more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063530/whats-the-difference-between-get-and-post-encryption

Answer (score 0):

You could always create some rewrite rules.  That way the original filenames are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the php **file_get_contents** function inside your php code

for example and save this to a variable:
Example:

```
$myinfo =file_get_contents(...myfacebookurljson..)
```

So others won´t be able to see the URL.