# what is the difference between data and params in requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, parameters

I am using `python requests` module, I send my params like this before:

```
requests.post(url=url, params=params)
```

but today, I find that I send my data like this, it fails, I change to this:

```
requests.post(url=url, data=params)
```

then it is ok, what is the difference between `data` and `params`?

I observed that the request got a header `X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest`, is it because of this?

Comment: Are you sure you weren't getting rather than posting?

Comment: what was the error you got when sending it in params?

Comment: roger, shame on you. As u can easily check in the history log of this thread, I was the first one answering your question correctly, while @ZN13 gave an incorrect answer. Then, AFTER my answer, he edited his answer and corrected it, and u finally marked his answer as the good one. That behaviour from him is sad, but u are encouraging it by rewarding him like that. I am glad that the overwhelming majority of this community is not like u guys.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the [requests documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/):

- A `requests.post(url, data=data)` will make an [HTTP POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) request, and
- A `requests.get(url, params=params)` will make an [HTTP GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request

To understand the difference between the two, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477374).

Here's how params can be used in a GET:

```
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', params=payload)
print(r.text)
```

Which outputs

```
{
  "args": {
    "key1": "value1", 
    "key2": "value2"
  }, 
  [...]
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get?key1=value1&key2=value2"
}
```

Notice that the payload ended up in the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) of the URL. Since they ended up there, they are viewable by anyone who has access to the URL, which is why you shouldn't use query strings for sensitive data like passwords.

Here's how data can be used in a POST:

```
payload = 'foobar'
r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

Which outputs

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "foobar", 
  [...]
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Notice how the POST data does not show up in the query strings, as they are transmitted through the body of the request instead.

---

Critique of this answer has pointed out that there are more options. I never denied such a thing in my original answer, but let's take a closer look.

The documentation examples always show:

- The params keyword used for GET, and
- The data keyword used for POST

But that doesn't mean they are mutually exclusive.

In theory you could mix the two together in a POST:

```
data = 'foobar'
params = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', params=params, data=data)
print(r.text)
```

Which outputs

```
{
  "args": {
    "key1": "value1", 
    "key2": "value2"
  }, 
  "data": "foobar", 
  [...]
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post?key1=value1&key2=value2"
}
```

But you cannot mix data into a GET:

```
data = 'foobar'
params = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', params=params, data=data)
print(r.text)
```

Outputs:

```
{
  "args": {
    "key1": "value1", 
    "key2": "value2"
  }, 
  [...]
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get?key1=value1&key2=value2"
}
```

Notice how the data field is gone.

Comment: post will not send data in URL. get method does.

Comment: @SekarRamu It seems that the code example I wrote was right, but I mistyped the text above so instead of `requests.get` I wrote `requests.post`. This should now be fixed.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, there are two different **methods**:

- `requests.post()` makes a POST request (placing all the parameters in the body)
- `requests.get()` makes a GET request (placing all the parameters in the URL)

Then, [according to the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), you can choose between two **parameters** to send all the key/value data:

- `params=`, without string modifications.
- `data=`, applying a form-encoding string modification to the parameters.

So, you have 4 choices to send your request:

- `requests.post(url, params=)`
- `requests.post(url, data=)`
- `requests.get(url, params=)`
- `requests.get(url, data=)`

I don't think the currently accepted answer is correct. He is actually talking about `requests.post()` but using `requests.get()` in his own example.

Comment: Wrong. You cannot use the data keyword in a GET request. It just silently removes it.

Answer (score 1):

Params are sent in (appended to) the URI (`http://www.answer.com/here?param1=1&param2=2`) while data is sent in the [request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034144/what-does-it-mean-http-request-body).  Usually sensitive data or that sent in large volumes is posted in the body because it's easier to [secure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629222/are-querystring-parameters-secure-in-https-http-ssl) and doesn't lead to huge URIs.

Comment: Why is it easier to secure?

Comment: Because URIs are sent in plaintext and normally stored in server logs so if you are sending something like a security token/username/password then anyone can see (and use) it.

Comment: The data could still be sniffed. You can use `https://` to secure. edit: **No you can't**

Comment: No, you can't.  That secures only network level attacks
http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/02/20/how-secure-are-query-strings-over-https/

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's horrific. And also really helpful and informative.

Comment: @ZN13  r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=payload) should place the payload under 'forms' not 'data', unless you add a header which includes the content-type