# Creating a new JSESSIONID after authentication

Tags: security, liferay-6, jsessionid

When a user hits login page of a `Portal` (it could be `Liferay`, `Jboss Portal`..),  `JSESSIONID  cookie`is created by the `container`. After entering credentials in the login page, same `JSESSIONID` gets carried over.

Here, end user will come to know the `JSESSIONID`before he could get authenticated (by checking the `JSESSIONID` in the login page). This will increase vulnerability of the site for hacking because one can know the `JSESSIONID`  before one gets authenticated.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722151/what-is-the-vulnerability-of-having-jsessionid-on-first-request-only) advices to have a different `JSESSIONID` after authentication.

So, creating a new JSESSIOND can be achieved by `Portal` server being used (am using `Liferay CE 6.0`) or it has to be handled by web application developer? If it has to be handled by web application developer what is the best way to do?  `request.getSession(true)` is the only option?? If I need to instruct `Liferay` to create a new `JSESSIONID` after authentication how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks a lot like the session fixation problem I solved for Liferay 5.2.5 a long time ago. The solution consists of creating a custom Tomcat Valve that will force a new session ID. So the solution isn't really specific for Liferay and is dependent on if you use Tomcat or not.

I suspect it shouldn't be too difficult to adapt my old solution to a newer Liferay/Tomcat combination. You can find the necessary information about my solution in my old and currently unmaintained blog (if I only had more time...): [Fixing session fixation in Liferay](http://marvinsmutterings.blogspot.be/2010/02/fixing-session-fixation-in-liferay-on.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not that the user knows the session ID (the user always knows it, it is sent by his browser). The attack scenario is that the user, while logged out, clicks on the link that already has JSESSIONID embedded, then authenticates and this session becomes a logged-in session. Now someone who initially created the link can use the same session to act as the user. More details at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation

So yes, use the web or app server to re-set session ID after a user authenticates. You do not need to write it yourself. For Tomcat 7: http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/04/25/session-fixation-protection

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. BTW, sorry, I didnt mention my App server. Am using Jboss. I will check this out in Jboss. If you have any useful links kindly share. I hope Jboss will also have this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this issue by setting the following property to true like Liferay has as default.

```
#
# Set this to true to invalidate the session when a user logs into the
# portal. This helps prevents phishing. Set this to false if you need the
# guest user and the authenticated user to have the same session.
#
# Set this to false if the property "company.security.auth.requires.https"
# is set to true and you want to maintain the same credentials across HTTP
# and HTTPS sessions.
#
session.enable.phishing.protection=true
```

Answer (score 0):

@Thiago:

This `session.enable.phishing.protection=true` is by default true in `portal.properties`. Anyhow, I have added this entry in `portal-ext.properties`. But, even then `JSESSIONID` remains same before and after login.

I have implemented a `filter` as per this [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-jsessionid-harmful). After implementing this filter, when I hit login page of Liferay, one `JSESSIONID` gets created. After I enter the credentials and login, the same `JSESSIONID` is retained.

I have implemented this `filter` in a `Servlet` and not in any of my `Portlets` or in Liferay's ROOT application. My `Servlet` is deployed in LR + Jboss AS bundle. Am first hitting the `Servlet` and from here I have a link which will redirect to Liferay's login page. I have implemented this `filter` in my `Servlet` because Container will append `JSESSIONID` for first time request as it doesn't know if cookies are enabled or not. Since, `JSESSIONID` is getting appended, am not able to retrieve my images in `Servlet` (because url is myImage.jpg;jsessionid=). Hence, I have implemented this `filter`.

**Is this `filter` conflicting with Liferay's configuration? Even after setting `session.enable.phishing.protection=true` same `JSESSIONID` is retained means what else could be the problem?**

Comment: @Thiago : I have posted my observations above

Answer (score 0):

Put this code inside the `portal-ext.properties`.

It will fix the problem, each and every time logged in, new session id will be generated.

```
session.enable.phishing.protection=true
com.liferay.util.servlet.SessionParameters=true
```