# what are the following attack strings trying to do?

Tags: security

I have found few attack GET requests on a web application.

```
mysite.com/login/auth;jsessionid=%22%20or%20%22d%22=%22d

mysite.com/login/auth;jsessionid=1%20and%2013=3%20--%20-

mysite.com/login/auth;jsessionid=C5C7348B296E4E39E84DD6B4BC93191D?alert(14721858.07197)<a>

mysite.com/login/auth;jsessionid=C5C7348B296E4E39E84DD6B4BC93191D?"style="x:expr/**/ession(alert(14721858.07267))
```

I will appreciate if anyone can tell what  any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are probing the url in several ways.

Session Prediction, (that looks like this):
mysite.com/login/auth;jsessionid=%22%20or%20%22d%22=%22d
mysite.com/login/auth;jsessionid=1%20and%2013=3%20--%20-

These links discuss that:
[what is the vulnerability of having Jsessionid on first request only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722151/what-is-the-vulnerability-of-having-jsessionid-on-first-request-only)

and this
[Testing for Session Fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Session_Fixation_(OTG-SESS-003))

And, UI hijacking and encoded URL hacking, discussed here:
[Three Semicolon Vulnerabilities](https://superevr.com/blog/2011/three-semicolon-vulnerabilities)

Good luck with that...