# How to consume Wcf rest servcie(Form authentication) from android client

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest, asp.net-membership

I built a wcf rest service with form authentication.  All the settings are set in config file.  This service needs to be consumed by android client.  So can any body please tell me how to send the request with log in credential to the rest service which is implemented using forms authentication.

Note: I know by implementing custom login service method we can validate the client and pass the cookie for the wcf rest method to authenticate.

I am looking for different solution like in single request we pass the credentials it validates the user with membership and gives the response.  Please let us know if u need any further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad question, so it will be difficult to answer completely.  For the WCF side, you can follow this: [How to Consume WCF Service with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669764/how-to-consume-wcf-service-with-android).  The idea is to return a token, or session, ID when the user successfully authenticates in the system, and each subsequent request uses this token to identify itself.  That approach uses SOAP, but you can also use REST too, which REST may be easier to consume in an Android client (REST worked great for me).

See this post, [Need advice on authentication for android client connecting to the WCF Rest setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643115/need-advice-on-authentication-for-android-client-connecting-to-the-wcf-rest-setu), for more guidance on the setup too.  When  I setup my authentication mechanism, I did a lot of research online to figure out the best approach to take.  A lot of people mentioned just use OAuth 2, and make sure you are using HTTPS communication.  So if you can use OAuth or Facebook/Twitter/Google+ for authenticating, that would be a good approach and take a lot of the headaches away.