# PHP - Track where users come from referer or direct?

Tags: php, tracking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get referrer URL - visitors coming from Paypal (HTTPS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430704/get-referrer-url-visitors-coming-from-paypal-https)

i'm trying to track my visitors, i'm using with `$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]`,

i have some problem, when users come from **https** refferal the `$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]` disappear In iOS 6.

in this case, how can i know if user come from refferer or direct, is there another way to know if users come directly ?

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-15.1.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the client does not send a referer header there is no way to know from where he comes.

However, you can determine if the user was on your site before by setting a cookie containing a timestamp and checking if that cookie already exists and how old the timestamp in it is.