# Can you at least get the domain of the https referer?

Tags: javascript, hitcounter, web-statistics

I've noticed that if a foreign `https:` site links to my non-https site, that I don't get anything in the HTTP Referer header at all.  I've experienced this with `access.log`, but I presume the same happens with JavaScript's `document.referrer`, too.

So, if the referrer is https, is there no way to get any information about it?  Not even the hostname / domain name?  Or is it possible to somehow get at least the domain, with JavaScript?

Also, I presume running my own site with `https` isn't going to solve this issue for me, correct?

Comment: check this http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47405/how-can-i-pass-referrer-header-from-my-https-domain-to-http-domains

Answer (score 4):

You should check this answer : [Get referrer URL - visitors coming from Paypal (HTTPS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430704/get-referrer-url-visitors-coming-from-paypal-https)

---

In case your site uses HTTP (not HTTPS) and the referer uses HTTPS, there is no Referrer being sent!

[HTTP RFC - 15.1.3 Encoding Sensitive Information in URI's](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-15.1.3) states:

> Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure)
> HTTP request if the referring page was transferred with a secure
> protocol.

So the only way to get the Referrer is to use HTTPS on your site.

Comment: So, if I move my site to https, I will be getting ALL https referrers?  Even inter-domain https referrers?

Comment: yes you can get inter-domain https referrers too if you're using HTTPS. I just practiced and commented here

Answer (score 1):

To get the `document.referrer`, You can use either of the options below:

1. You Need to convert your HTTP site to HTTPS.
2. Or you can add the below simple meta tag in your HTTPS site.

   `<meta name="referrer" content="always">`