# How to determine keywords from which the user came to the page?

Tags: php, google-analytics, http-referer, google-ads-api

I'm running a Google Adwords campaign, and I would like to know where my users came from.
I have a form allowing them to leave an application, and I need to attach the information about the keywords to the application user leaves.

Now I do two things:

**1. Attach information from $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to the form**. And I have my applications coming in the following format:

```
Name: name
Skype: skype
Referer: http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-6279739740619787&output=html&h=250&slotname=4467623023&adk=125461787&w=300&lmt=1384570112&flash=0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.softmozer.com%2Fdownloading-android%2Fviber-mobile&dt=1384598912575&bdt=1666&shv=r20131112&cbv=r20130906&saldr=sb&prev_slotnames=6478798083&correlator=1384598912354&frm=20&ga_vid=322040364.1384598912&ga_sid=1384598912&ga_hid=825269062&ga_fc=0&u_tz=480&u_his=2&u_java=1&u_h=640&u_w=360&u_ah=640&u_aw=360&u_cd=32&u_nplug=0&u_nmime=0&dff=arial&dfs=12&adx=0&ady=397&biw=980&bih=1543&oid=3&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.softmozer.com%2Fdownload-android%2Fviber-mobile.html&vis=1&fu=0&ifi=2&dtd=24&xpc=8EEeOm8Hca&p=http%3A//www.softmozer.com
```

But this way is bad for two reasons:

- HTTP_REFERER doesn't work in all browsers.
- Don't really know if getting keywords is possible in cases of all URLs like in the example.

**2. Set up goals in Google Analytics**. It allows me to know how many goals were accomplished from a specific keyword. But it doesn't allow to determine from which keyword I received that specific application.

What way would you suggest to determine keywords from which the user came to the page?

Answer (score 2):

Don't rely on referrer data. Google [switched all their traffic to HTTPS](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2296351/Goodbye-Keyword-Data-Google-Moves-Entirely-to-Secure-Search) recently, so no browsers will feed you referrer data. This is a browser security feature and not a Google filter, incidentally. You can read more about why at
[Can you at least get the domain of the https referer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551586/can-you-at-least-get-the-domain-of-the-https-referer)

Your Adwords and Analytics account should be [linked as described here](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1704341?hl=en). If they are linked, Google will feed keyword data (even from HTTPS) into your Analytics and you can track it there. This is done through a token Google passes so you can't get any data directly here. If you want it you will have to use the Google Analytics API to pull it.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know how exactly can I pull the adwords keywords after linking?

Comment: After linking it will be available to you in Analytics under `Acquisition > Keywords > Paid`