# Get Adwords keyword that lead user to the page from Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics-api

I asked a question about [how to determine keywords from which the user came to the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036079/how-to-determine-keywords-from-which-the-user-came-to-the-page).
I was suggested to link Google Adwords with Google Analytics and use Google Analytics API to pull the keywords.

What API methods can I use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the answer to my question: http://certifiedknowledge.org/blog/using-adwords-dynamic-parameters-in-links/