# How to get a referrer URL on Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

How to get a referrer URL on Angular 4?? For example say example.com is my angular website, if example.com is visited from an another php page say domaintwo.com/checkout.php. How can I identify the the referenced url(domaintwo.com/checkout.php) from my angular website..?? Am looking for a solution like `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` on PHP(same process needed on angular4). Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why do you need the referrer in your client script?

Comment: What's the error you get when you use document.referrer? Is there any compilation error? Share more details...

Comment: @bitsprint because you may have a static cached HTML / JS website that doesn't run any server side code on a new session - and there's nowhere else to get it

Answer (score 14):

Have you tried?

```
document.referrer
```

According to [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20090303/html.html#ID-95229140):

> *referrer* of type *DOMString*, *readonly*
>
> Returns the URI [[IETF RFC 2396](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20090303/references.html#RFC2396)] of the page that linked to this page. The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page
>   directly (not through a link, but, for example, via a bookmark).

Comment: note that a referal from HTTPS > HTTP doesn't provide the referrer to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551586/can-you-at-least-get-the-domain-of-the-https-referer