# Automatic login into phpmyadmin from other application

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

So I am building a PHP web application which can be used by students to learn concept of creating web pages connected to MariaDB database.

Each user of this application will be given a MariaDB database associated with his account. To avoid creating whole interface to interact with database I was thinking of using phpmyadmin.

Once user is logged in I want to provide him with a link he can click on in order to be redirected and logged in phpmyadmin. Each user of the application will have associated MariaDB account whose username and password are generated and stored on the server.

I searched in phpmyadmin documentation and I was thinking of setting `auth_type` option in the config to `cookie`. If I understood correctly when phpmyadmin is configured this way, normally users can login using MariaDB account credentials, when they do, their credentials are stored on the server in PHP session until they log out or the session expires.

So if this is correct, my question is, is somehow possible to create phpmyadmin PHP session and set session cookie, so when user is redirected to phpmyadmin he will be already logged in, or if this is wrong way to do this, is there the other way ?

Basically I want to be able to authenticate users with phpmyadmin from my application, like in Cpanel where users are just redirected to phpmyadmin.

Comment: https://lowendtalk.com/discussion/119441/how-cpanel-can-autologin-into-phpmyadmin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24463564/5947043

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24490934/5947043

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ADyson, i believe using `singon`  `auth_type` is solution to my problem.