# JAVA EE Rest conditional GET methods on QueryParams

Tags: java, rest, get, query-string

I would like to have two `GET` methods on my Rest resource class.
one would react if query param has `value1` and second on `value2`

Lets say:

```
@Path("/myApi")
public class MyApiService {

     @GET
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     public Response methodOne(...) {
         ...
         return ...;
     }

     @GET
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     public Response methodTwo(...) {
         ...
         return ...;   
     }
```

How to achieve conditional routing for query params

I would like to `methodOne()` reacts if `QueryParam` is `?type=one` and `methodTwo()` if `QueryParam` is `?type=two`

Comment: Would you please tell us why you think this is necessary?

Comment: One option is to use [Sub-Resource Locators](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28978111/2587435)

Comment: @Tichodroma I would like to separate methods, so in for example in swagger you could see more methods. I think methods per different query param isnt so stupid as it looks like...

Answer (score 0):

Choosing servlet handlers based on `QueryParam` is not a good aproach, and by default no library gives you oportunity to do so.
The closest that comes to mind is `PathParam`, that is something like `Path("\api\{param1}\{param2}")` but it's not what you are looking for.

To achieve want your want just

- unregister those methods as servlet handlers (Optional, if you don't need them outside of queryparam selection scope)
- define a new one that will choose based on `query param`

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

```
public Response methodThree(QueryParam('type') String type) {
return type.equals("type1") ? this.methodOne() : this.methodTwo();   
}
```

Comment: this was option I thought so, I think this is only option :(

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two methods with identical parameters for the same path.
It's not pretty, but it will work..

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response myMethod(@QueryParam("type") String type){

 if(type.equals("one"))
     return methodOne();
 else
     return methodTwo();
}
```