# Should PUT request be used to delete a resource?

Tags: rest, http, put

I have a situation where I don't know how to manage it. I have a resource that has a flag "undeniable." Denying a post, would delete it from the database, so using

```
DELETE /v1/posts/post-id-here
```

would have been just fine; this way the undeniable post would have been just ignored with 404. But my undeniable post would have a counter on how many times it was getting denied, so I think this kills the purpose of DELETE. That's why I was heading towards PUT request but I can't find anywhere about validity of removing a resource on PUT request. I was thinking something like the following:

```
PUT /v1/posts/post-id-here/deny
```

which would either delete the post or increment the counter, with both returning 200 OK. Is it valid? Or should I try to separate them in the client side, where the undeniable posts output the PUT url and the deniable ones output the DELETE url; and if DELETE was called on undeniable one, 404 would be returned? Or is there a third option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `PUT` is used to update the complete state of the resource. I think that it's not exactly what you want to do. I would rather see the use of a method `POST` on the resource `/v1/posts/post-id-here`. This corresponds to the action of undenying the post. As far as I understand, such action will do the following:

- Set the flag `undeniable` to `true` if its value was `false` before
- Increment a counter (a field `undenyCounter` for example)

There is also the method `PATCH` that allows partial update of the resource state but I think that it's exactly your use case, since you want to increment a field...

To finish, using an action as a path parameter isn't really RESTful ;-) You can have a look at this question for more details about how to handle this: [How to Update a REST Resource Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28638071/how-to-update-a-rest-resource-collection/28658601#28658601).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry