# HTTPS url not encrypted

Tags: android, ssl, https, retrofit, charles-proxy

I'm using **Charles proxy** to fetch all the requests coming from my Android app to a webservice.

The thing is Charles shows me the complete request, meaning I can see the whole URL, headers and body so I can see *www.example.com/rest/resource/param1/param2*,
the JSON I send with it and also the authentication header.

After reading several posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499591/are-https-urls-encrypted) and [this one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7705/does-ssl-tls-https-hide-the-urls-being-accessed) I thought the good part of working with the TLS was that one could only get the domain name from the URL, in this case *www.example.com*

To make sure it's not the client's fault, I requested the webservice resource with **Retrofit** and **HttpsURLConnection** and I could see the whole request both times.

I guess also the certificate is properly installed because it is shown in the browser every time an *https* request is made. Am I missing something else here or is this the normal behaviour?

So far I couldn't find a reason for this to happen so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug with Charles proxy you must install a certificate on your browser (client).

With https the URL **is encrypted**.

But because you choose to use that proxy, your browser establish a secure connection to that proxy, and the proxy to the website. So, only 1) you, 2) the proxy 3)the website can decrypt the https traffic.

**By installing a CA certificate** on your browser, **you allow the person detaining the corresponding private key (in your case, your proxy) to impersonate (so, decrypt with a MITM) any website**.

Comment: Ok thanks, now I get it, could you also recommend a way to prevent this attack?

Comment: It's not an attack, you volontary installed that certificate. To avoid that "attack" just don't install it ;)

Comment: yes, but anyone installing the Charles root certificate would also be able to decrypt the request.

Comment: I don't know specifically about Charles, if they care about security, each costumer use a different certificate. But anyway it's safer to disable that certificate after your tests.

Comment: When you attempt to install such a certificate (called a self signed certificate), the OS will most likely give you a security warning saying that it should NOT be done. You must click proceed to make that install on your device. In doing so, you purposefully allow Charles to perform a MITM attack on you.