# Token authentication for django channels

Tags: django, reactjs, websocket, token, django-channels

im trying to integrate React , django and django channels together , however im facing some trouble trying to authenticate the socket connection.

There are some posts over here: 
[first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43392889/how-do-you-authenticate-a-websocket-with-token-authentication-on-django-channels)
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230340/how-to-authenticate-a-user-in-websocket-connection-in-django-channels-when-using)

But they do not talk about how to utilize it over the front end portion.

There are some posts which recommends to put the token within the URL , for example :

```
WebSocket('wss://example.com/my-ws-endpoint/?token=' + token, ...)
```

But there seems to be lots of security red flags in doing so. Therefore is there a simple easy way to resolve the token authentication issue for channel websockets here?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this](https://yeti.co/blog/token-based-header-authentication-for-websockets-behind-nodejs/). It uses a http-proxy middleware to put the token in the request header instead of putting it within the URL.
Also, you can read about a good method of authentication in Django channels [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361358/6287044).

Comment: Hey brother ,  thanks for taking the time to answer my question , i have read through the link you have provided me however , it seems abit complicated to implement. I have adopted another method which is to send tokens via a cookie header : [linkl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61413375/django-channels-custom-token-authenticated-websocket-keeps-disconnecting-err-con)