# Authentication with Django channels using Tokens - How do I use this mixin

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-channels

My website hosts a lot of APIs(CRUDs) using DJR. I am using DJR Token based authentication and for testing I would add this header to postman

```
Key : Authorization 
value : Token 826fdf3067b07afdf9edd89a6c9facd9920de8b8
```

and Django Rest Framework would easily be able to authenticate the user.
Now I inlcuded Django channels constantly 1.1.5 and wanted to know how I could do token based authentication. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43392889/how-do-you-authenticate-a-websocket-with-token-authentication-on-django-channels) post and it suggests that I copy [this](https://gist.github.com/leonardoo/9574251b3c7eefccd84fc38905110ce4) mixin to the project. I just started with Django-channels and am not sure how to include that mixin to my code. Currently I have something like this

```
@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_connect(message):
    user = message.user
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True}) #Send back Acceptance response. 

@channel_session_user
def chat_join(message):
    user = message.user #Get authenticated user
```

I have the following two questions

1-How do I include that mixin in my current project ? I know you include mixins in classes using `class classname(SomeMixin)`. How would I go about including this mixin into my code ?

2-Will I need to include an authentication token in my json message that I send to the websocket ?

Any suggestions would be great.
`