# Django Channels JWT Authentication

Tags: django, jwt, django-channels, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm trying to access the user in the scope in my Consumer.py and grab some user related models from the DB. However, it seems like `AuthMiddlewareStack` I'm using for authenticating all the websocket connections is not working correctly.

What is the best/secure way to be able to authenticate websocket connection in django channels when I'm using JWT Tokens `django-rest-framework-simplejwt` for authentication in my REST Framework?

Comment: You can check out [`channels-auth-token-middlewares` `QueryStringSimpleJWTAuthTokenMiddleware`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76473621) which helps fill this need.

Answer (score 13):

Channels 3 auth is different from channels 2 you will have to create your own auth middleware for that start by creating a file channelsmiddleware.py

```
"""General web socket middlewares
"""

from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from rest_framework_simplejwt.exceptions import InvalidToken, TokenError
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import UntypedToken
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTTokenUserAuthentication
from rest_framework_simplejwt.state import User
from channels.middleware import BaseMiddleware
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from django.db import close_old_connections
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
from jwt import decode as jwt_decode
from django.conf import settings


@database_sync_to_async
def get_user(validated_token):
    try:
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(id=validated_token["user_id"])
        # return get_user_model().objects.get(id=toke_id)
        print(f"{user}")
        return user
   
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return AnonymousUser()



class JwtAuthMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
       # Close old database connections to prevent usage of timed out connections
        close_old_connections()

        # Get the token
        token = parse_qs(scope["query_string"].decode("utf8"))["token"][0]

        # Try to authenticate the user
        try:
            # This will automatically validate the token and raise an error if token is invalid
            UntypedToken(token)
        except (InvalidToken, TokenError) as e:
            # Token is invalid
            print(e)
            return None
        else:
            #  Then token is valid, decode it
            decoded_data = jwt_decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=["HS256"])
            print(decoded_data)
            # Will return a dictionary like -
            # {
            #     "token_type": "access",
            #     "exp": 1568770772,
            #     "jti": "5c15e80d65b04c20ad34d77b6703251b",
            #     "user_id": 6
            # }

            # Get the user using ID
            scope["user"] = await get_user(validated_token=decoded_data)
        return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)


def JwtAuthMiddlewareStack(inner):
    return JwtAuthMiddleware(AuthMiddlewareStack(inner))
```

you can import it into your consumer's routing.py or asgi.py file like this

```
"""
ASGI config for config project.
It exposes the ASGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.
For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/asgi/
"""

import os
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from chat.consumers import ChatConsumer
from django.urls import path, re_path
from .channelsmiddleware import JwtAuthMiddlewareStack

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.dev")

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": get_asgi_application(),
        "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
            JwtAuthMiddlewareStack(
                URLRouter(
                    [
                        #path(),your routes here 
                    ]
                )
            ),
        ),
    }
)
```

Comment: hi elite , thanks for answer , just note :  i am using djangorestframework-simplejwt ver 5.1.0 ,   and i get error when try to import "from rest_framework_simplejwt.state import User" , what is the replacement  ?.

Comment: You don't need that line of code. U can use the User from django.contrib.auth.models

Answer (score 8):

Well I had the same problem. First of all you can't do JWT authentication with django channels because the only thing that you can send through your channels is `query string` and you can't set header parameters or such thing like `http` protocol (especially if your using `JavaScript` as your client side). I didn't want to send my token as query string because of security purpose (because every one can see it). So I explain my solution here and maybe it can solve your problem too. I created an API for registering in my socket and in that API I returned a ticket (uuid type) as a response and in the same API I cached this ticket based on a user:

```
class RegisterFilterAPIView(APIView):
    """
        get:
            API view for retrieving ticket uuid.
    """
    authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ticket_uuid = str(uuid4())

        if request.user.is_anonymous:
            cache.set(ticket_uuid, False, TICKET_EXPIRE_TIME)
        else:
            # You can set any condition based on logged in user here
            cache.set(ticket_uuid, some_conditions, TICKET_EXPIRE_TIME)

        return Response({'ticket_uuid': ticket_uuid})
```

After this part I sent this ticket as a query string to my socket like:

```
var endpoint = 'ws://your/socket/endpoint/?ticket_uuid=some_ticket';
var newSocket = new WebSocket(endpoint);

newSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log("message", e)
};
newSocket.onopen = function (e) {
    console.log("open", e);
};
newSocket.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log("error", e)
};
newSocket.onclose = function (e) {
    console.log("close", e)
};
```

Note that the above codes are written in `JS` so you should change it to something else based on your requirements. And finally in my consumer I handled this ticket which is created in my register API:

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl
from django.core.cache import cache
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer


class FilterConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        try:
            query_string = self.scope['query_string'].decode('utf-8')
            query_params = dict(parse_qsl(query_string))
            ticket_uuid = query_params.get('ticket_uuid')
            self.scope['has_ticket'] = cache.get(ticket_uuid)
            if not cache.delete(ticket_uuid): # I destroyed ticket for performance and security purposes
                raise Exception('ticket not found')
        except:
            await self.close()
            return

        await self.accept()
```

So now you have a register API (like obtain token API) which is safe and you can generate a token based on your JWT token but make sure your server supports a cache backend service. You can also set `self.scope['user']` in your websocket connect method based on your ticket value. I hope this can solve your problem.

Comment: Leaving this for future Readers :
Regarding Security Risk while using tokens in query parameter : Check the discussion in comments of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46348868/14264497).