# How to use token base authentication in Django channels and testing on postman

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-channels

By using Django channels I want to use token authentication and test on postman but I can't connect after using authentication.It's a notification app where user receive notification on websocket without refresh and without authentication It is working fine.. I have uploaded all the files .Please check it out I will be thankful to you.
**consumers.py**

```
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from channels.auth import login
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync, sync_to_async
import json
from .models import *

class OrderProgress(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.user = self.scope["user"]
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['order_id']
        print('the result is ....', self.scope['path'])
        print('the user is', self.scope["user"])
        self.room_group_name = 'order_%s' % self.room_name
        print('order is this......', )
        print(self.room_group_name)

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        if self.scope['user'].is_authenticated:
            order = Order.give_order_details(self.room_name)
            self.accept()

            self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                'payload': order
            }))

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    def receive(self, text_data):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'order_status',
                'payload': text_data
            }
        )
    def order_status(self, event):
        print('data in event............', event)
        data = json.loads(event['value'])
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'payload': data
        }))




               **middeleware.py**
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from channels.middleware import BaseMiddleware

@database_sync_to_async
def get_user(token_key):
    try:
        token = Token.objects.get(key=token_key)
        return token.user
    except Token.DoesNotExist:
        return AnonymousUser()

class TokenAuthMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, inner):
        super().__init__(inner)

    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        try:
            token_key = (dict((x.split('=') for x in scope['query_string'].decode().split("&")))).get('token', None)
        except ValueError:
            token_key = None
        scope['user'] = AnonymousUser() if token_key is None else await get_user(token_key)
        return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)

                  **asgi.py**

import os
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from home.middleware import TokenAuthMiddleware
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import home.routing
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from home.token_auth import TokenAuthMiddlewareStack

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'pizza2.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': TokenAuthMiddleware(
        URLRouter(
        home.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
    ))
})

       **routing.py**
from django.urls import path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
  path('ws/pizza/<order_id>', consumers.OrderProgress.as_asgi()),
  path('ws/pizza1/', consumers.OrderConsumer.as_asgi()),

]

**models.py**


# Create your models here.
from django.db import models
import string
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
import channels.layers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.dispatch import receiver
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
import json

from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator
import random
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer


class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=False, unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=100, null=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


def random_string_generator(size=10, chars=string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))


CHOICES = (
    ("Order Recieved", "Order Recieved"),
    ("Baking", "Baking"),
    ("Baked", "Baked"),
    ("Out for delivery", "Out for delivery"),
    ("Order recieved", "Order recieved"),
)


class Order(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=100, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CHOICES, default="Order Recieved", null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if self.order_id is None:
            self.order_id = random_string_generator()
        print("Error")
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def give_order_details(order_id):
        instance = Order.objects.filter(order_id=order_id).first()
        data = {}
        data['order_id'] = instance.order_id
        data['amount'] = instance.amount
        data['status'] = instance.status
        data['date'] = str(instance.date)
        progress_percentage = 20
        if instance.status == 'Order Recieved':
            progress_percentage = 20
        elif instance.status == 'Baking':
            progress_percentage = 40
        elif instance.status == 'Baked':
            progress_percentage = 60
        elif instance.status == 'Out for delivery':
            progress_percentage = 80
        elif instance.status == 'Order recieved':
            progress_percentage = 100

        data['progress'] = progress_percentage

        return data

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_id


@receiver(post_save, sender=Order)
def order_status_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if not created:
        print("###################")
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        data = {}
        data['order_id'] = instance.order_id
        data['amount'] = instance.amount
        data['status'] = instance.status
        data['date'] = str(instance.date)
        progress_percentage = 20
        if instance.status == 'Order Recieved':
            progress_percentage = 20
        elif instance.status == 'Baking':
            progress_percentage = 40
        elif instance.status == 'Baked':
            progress_percentage = 60
        elif instance.status == 'Out for delivery':
            progress_percentage = 80
        elif instance.status == 'Order recieved':
            progress_percentage = 100

        data['progress'] = progress_percentage
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            'order_%s' % instance.order_id, {
                'type': 'order_status',
                'value': json.dumps(data)
            }
        )

            **postman**

[I want to connect and recive meassage fromm websocket but it denied please corect me I will be thankful to you][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3fyP.png
```

Comment: maybe this post can help you..     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65297148/django-channels-jwt-authentication/65300665#65300665