# Using Django REST framework for real-time chat?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I'm trying create a real-time chat app with `Django` and `Vuejs`. I would like to use `django-rest-framework` for this but I don't know how to make it real-time. I have used `django-channels` before but I'm curious if I can use only `django-rest-framework` as an alternative or maybe integrated it with `django-channels`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to integrate them, because django channels are sending and accepting json data to websocket, as your rest framework api does. Rest framework is made for api, django channels for websockets, they won't have nothing in common cuz they have different implementations. The only thing you could consider integrating is rest framework auth inside django channels see: [How do you authenticate a websocket with token authentication on django channels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43392889/how-do-you-authenticate-a-websocket-with-token-authentication-on-django-channels)

Answer (score 0):

I also am a beginner but from what I know.. rest framework isn't suitable for "real-time" working of web-application cause it can't make a 2-way connection (like.. send data to other memebers in group without them making a call to it) for this purpose django channels is a better medthod cause its making a websocket connection.

do let me know if i m wrong.