# How does Charles see domain when do not enable ssl proxying

Tags: ssl, https, proxy, charles-proxy

When Charles do not enable ssl proxying, Charles still see the domain, but i can't see the domain when i check connection in Wireshark, Why? How does Charles do?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the host (domain) is not encrypted in HTTPS protocol. It is delivered in plain text.

For Wireshark, actually you can intercept `ClientHello` packet and find the host in plain text there. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/38727920/707451