# Encrypt Url Parameter In asp.net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Get)
{          
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Id)
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

1-When we click On Submit Button this will Create Url Like this

```
    http://localhost:53734/Controller/Action?id=10  
    //10 is input From Textbox
```

I want to encrypt Id parameter  like
 http://localhost:53734/Controller/Action?id=encrypted Value Of 10

Comment: Use HTTPS instead. If you encrypt anything in *Javascript* it will be obvious to whoever has access to the page source. That includes the hackers that may hack any intermediate proxy, router.

Comment: @MohammadAlghanem this is primarily a Javascript question.

Comment: What are you trying to protect against? Prevent someone between client and server from stealing the parameters? Or prevent the server-side code from reading the parameter? Encryption could protect only against the second case

Comment: Only want to protect Url  server Side user Can't see the actual value of id Paramete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to "hide" and "protect" the request. The best solution is to:

- Use HTTPS so the transport will provide encryption
- All parameters in GET and POST are encrypted (more [Are HTTPS URLs encrypted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499591/are-https-urls-encrypted)).

If it is not possible, use RSACryptProvider to encrypt parameter. The universal encryption code is in MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: [URLs are also encrypted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499591/are-https-urls-encrypted). The *entire* payload is encrypted, not just parts of it.

Comment: As for using AES (ie RSA) the Javascript code would have to encrypt the parameter using a common password. Both the encryption code and the password would be exposed to any MITM attack.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are right, I will update an answer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but his code is not JavaScript it is classic ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Who's going to *encrypt* the form's fields?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos nothing, but in most cases, it is just redundant. Usually, it looks like security by obscurity.