# What are the security risks of accessing a password protected website from within a private iOS app by embedding the password in the URL?

Tags: ios, security, https, jasonette

I would like to develop a privately distributed iOS app with [jasonette](https://jasonette.com/) that acts as a gateway to my password protected website. The credentials to access the website would be embedded directly in the URL, i.e. "https://user:pass@website.com"

Which security risks are involved with this solution?

Here are some further considerations:

- The website should be only be accessible to those who own the app.
- The website in question is protected by SSL
- To those familiar with jasonette: both the URL pointing to the configuration JSON and the URLs within the JSON would be using embedded passwords
- The app will be restricted to an organization on Apple Store Connect

Here are some of my concerns:

- Undesired users of the device finding the login credentials in plaintext
- Malware on the device obtaining the login credentials from my app
- Man in the middle obtaining the login credentials while making a connection to the website (does the username:password part of the url get encrypted?)

Comment: [Are HTTPS URLs encrypted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499591/are-https-urls-encrypted)