# Which elements are secured by HTTPS?

Tags: html, encryption, https

I am studying for an HTML course and this is one of the practice questions for the exam. Many people seem to disagree on the answers provided in the comment section, so I was curious to see if anybody here knows the real answer.

What three elements does HTTPS encrypt?

> a. browser cookies
> b. login information
> c. port numbers
> d. website URL
> e. login information
> f. meta data

My answers are D & E for sure, and maybe A? I don't know if browser cookies are actually encrypted. If anybody has an explanation for this question with some detail that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Correct Answer: **ADE**
Explanation/Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499591/are-https-urls-encrypted

Comment: Thank you for the quick response/thread which explains this in great detail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is wrong.

> a. browser cookies

Yes.

> b. login information

This could mean anything. Possible ways to send login information to the web application:

1. in URL (either in userinfo or as part of path or query parameters),
2. as part of http headers such as `Authorization`, `Bearer` or even `Cookie`,
3. as part of http body such as form values during POST.

All of them are encrypted by HTTP over TLS (https).

> c. port numbers

As part of the URL, sure, but an observer can still see which port you connected to, so no.

> d. website URL

Yes.

> e. login information

Exactly the same as B.

> f. meta data

Whatever that means. Only HTTP/1.1 defines metadata as part of RFC7230. Since even HTTP/1.1 runs over TLS, that's encrypted too.

I count 5 of 6 answer options to be correct with respect to being "secure".

Answer (score 1):

Hypertext is text that includes references to other text that the reader can navigate. HTTPS is literally HTTP over SSL/TLS. HTTPS is the combination of HTTP+SSL/TLS.An extra layer security is used over the HTTP denotes the 's' in HTTPS.

When you make an HTTPS connection, the device you’re using sends a TCP request via port 443. Once that connection begins, it’s only encrypting application-layer data, meaning the information exchanged between the client and server – messages, cookies, the content on a web page, etc. These files can't be accessed by an intruder. But information like the webpage adrress, our location, ip etc. is not secured.

Comment: u can refer this page for more information about connection layers and security.
https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/what-does-https-protect/