# Encryption of HTTPS headers

Tags: https, http-headers

To what extent, if at all, are HTTPS headers encrypted?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187655/are-https-headers-encrypted

Comment: thanks, for some reason that didn't come up when i searched, but i just found it as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are encrypted in transit through SSL.  There is no special encryption dedicated to headers, HTTPS encrypts the entire message.

Answer (score 2):

All headers are encrypted in HTTPS. You may want to look at some [documentation on how SSL and TLS work](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2928/index.htm?info/rzain/rzainhowssl.htm).

Answer (score 2):

SSL sets up a private authenticated link to the server and then sends an http request over that link. The evil-doer snooping on the link cant actually tell from just watching the connection that http is being used. SSL its self has some unencrypted headers that it uses to establish this connection though these should not be confused with the headers that are part of the http protocol.