# How we can modify https header?

Tags: https, header

How can I modify https header? I want to implement an additional information inside the https header. Is there any way I can realize this?

Currently I'm focusing on Firefox and Mozilla NSS.

Thanks.

Comment: At what time do you want to modify it? You may just use a proxy, What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you hosting the page or do you want to add information to something on the wire?

Comment: silky - you cannot use a proxy to modify https headers, or to intercept the traffic in any way, really. the headers are encrypted - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187655/are-https-headers-encrypted

Answer (score 1):

There's really no HTTPS header - it's HTTP header but it's send over SSL (so it's encrypted). If you own the server and handling requests there then you can pretty much add any header stuff if you are creating request anew (e.g. with HttpClient) but if you are intercepting it then I don't think there's much you can do since again - it's all encrypted

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want your browser to send additional information to the server inside the headers. There appears to be a plugin for this called [modify headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/967) which might do what you want. But there's not much point - any data you want to send to your application can more easily be send in your GET or POST.

If you want to send additional headers from your web application to the client, this varies by language. In PHP for instance, you call the [header function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) with the data you want to send. But again, there is not much point unless you have some browser-side application that reads these headers (like the FireBug plugin, which uses custom headers to display PHP debugging information).