# Does Amazon S3 support HTTP request with basic authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to set up an Amazon S3 account, create a bucket, upload some data, and that this data will be available using HTTP GET **with basic authentication**.

I know that there are several ways to get the S3 data authenticated (query string and such), but I would like to be able to provide a simple username/password scheme for authentication.

Is this possible?

Comment: you can use [s3auth.com](http://www.s3auth.com), which is a free hosted solution for what you need

Comment: [s3auth](http://www.s3auth.com/) is definitely the solution for this.

Comment: @RaymondKalonji It s3auth is not official by AWS

Comment: @yegor256  Does not seem to be working anymore.

Answer (score 69):

This is now possible using CloudFront and Lambda@Edge (generally available since July 2017 in the us-east-1 region).

1. Create a S3 bucket
2. Setup a CloudFront distribution in-front of the bucket, restricting access to the bucket so that only CloudFront can access it directly
3. Create a Lambda function, which will mimic Basic HTTP Auth handshake with the browser. Assign it to the CloudFront `Viewer Request` behavior.

Here's the Lambda function:
https://gist.github.com/lmakarov/e5984ec16a76548ff2b278c06027f1a4

Here's an article with more details:
https://medium.com/@lmakarov/serverless-password-protecting-a-static-website-in-an-aws-s3-bucket-bfaaa01b8666

Comment: Should this be triggered on `Viewer Request`?

Comment: Hi, I added the htaccess authentication with lambda function and cloudfront. Now i want to remove it. How i can?

Comment: This can be done with a CloudFront Function as mentioned by jeroenvollenbrock in a comment on that Gist. Our team simplified it further: https://gist.github.com/jeroenvollenbrock/94edbbc62adc986d6d6a9a3076e66f5b#gistcomment-3966871 Jeroen says it's cheaper and faster though I haven't verified that.

Answer (score 32):

The short answer is no, not using basic auth. But here is a way that is effectively the same as basic auth, and that is easily than other solutions listed. I believe it is secure, but I don't know for sure.

You can set conditions on s3 buckets that match the headers on the request. As an example you can use the `useragent`, and `referer` headers as something equivalent to username and password in basic auth. Normally the useragent is the browser, and OS (like `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0)`, and the referer is the previous webpage.

Here is an example s3 bucket policy that allows putting objects, and getting objects by matching the useragent, and referer (note change: `BUCKETNAME`, `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD`, `AWS_REGION`, and `FILENAME` to your details):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "allow-username-and-password-access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:UserAgent": "USERNAME",
                    "aws:Referer": "PASSWORD"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To put a resource in the bucket you can use a curl request like this (note change: `BUCKETNAME`, `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD`, `AWS_REGION`, and `FILENAME`):

```
curl --user-agent USERNAME --referer PASSWORD --upload-file "FILENAME" --request PUT "https://s3-AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME/FILENAME"
```

To get use the resource you can use something like this:

```
curl --user-agent USERNAME --referer PASSWORD "https://s3-AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME/FILENAME" > FILENAME
```

Once again, I believe this is secure, as the useragent, and referer should be encrypted if you are using https, but please tell me if it is not.

Comment: Excellent. This is exactly what I've been looking for!. I agree that it is secured.

Comment: One insecurity of this is that it stores your password in plaintext in your security policy.  That's generally considered bad practice.

Comment: This is an insecure approach. Credentials are visible for all men-in-the-middle routers, hubs and so on.

Comment: Thanks @liberborn but the HTTP headers are actually encrypted with HTTPS
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187655/are-https-headers-encrypted

Comment: My bad @JordanStewart. It is secure indeed. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: AWS S3 doesn't support HTTPS website endpoints, please check this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteEndpoints.html

Answer (score 24):

You can develop it yourself as a web app or a part of your existing application. It will consume HTTP requests, retrieve their URI component, convert it to S3 object name and use [getObject()](https://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/SOAPGetObject.html) to get its content (using one of available S3 SDKs, for example [AWS Java SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/)).

Otherwise, you can try a hosted solution - [s3auth.com](http://www.s3auth.com) (I'm a developer). It's an open source project, and you can see how this mechanism is implemented internally at [one of its core classes](https://github.com/yegor256/s3auth/blob/master/s3auth-relay/src/main/java/com/s3auth/relay/SecuredHost.java). HTTP request is processed by the service and then re-translated to Amazon S3 internal authentication scheme:

[image]

This architecture diagram explains how the project is implemented. The PNG picture is loaded from Amazon S3 bucket `maven.s3auth.com`, which is not readable anonymously. Full URL of this image is

```
http://s3auth:s3auth@maven.s3auth.com/texry/packages.png
```

Check also this article: [Basic HTTP Auth for S3 Buckets](https://www.yegor256.com/2014/04/21/s3-http-basic-auth.html)

Comment: To clarify the last bit of your answer, the standard URL for a resource would be `http://maven.s3auth.com/texry/packages.png`, but once it's authenticated it becomes `http://s3auth:s3auth@maven.s3auth.com/texry/packages.png`, correct?

Comment: What is "the standard URL"? :) The URL where the document can be downloaded is `http://s3auth:s3auth@maven.s3auth.com/texry/packages.png`, and it includes authentication information

Comment: @yegor256 i did try to implement in my account but i can't configure.so can you help me to provide step by step tutorial or something else??????

Comment: Does s3auth first load the file from S3 to its own server and then transfer it to the user? Or somehow redirect? I can't imagine it redirecting without exposing the S3 link.

Comment: s3auth streams the file from S3 to you. It doesn't store the file locally or in memory, but streams through

Comment: I know it's been a while, but shouldn't S3 auth use https? In combination with using basicauth the credentials are actually transferred in cleartext since it only uses base64 encoding.

Comment: @yegor256 s3auth does not seem to be loading anymore.

Answer (score 14):

By layering multiple AWS services you can achieve something close to Basic HTTP Authorisation.

1. Create a s3 static site.
2. Create a CloudFront Distribution to serve the s3 static site (use the static site url and not the bucket name)
3. Use AWS WAF to create a rule which only allows requests with the correct http Authorization header. This will be a sting match rule on the contents of the Authorization header.
4. Use Route53 to route a custom domain to the CloudFront Distribution

You should now have a static site which can only be accessed with the correct username and password.

**NOTE:** using this setup you will not be prompted for you credentials as the request is blocked with a *403 Forbidden* instead of *401 Unauthorized*.

**NOTE:** You can create a CloudFront distribution in front of a s3 bucket directly, but you will not be able to default to a root index file in sub-folders.

Comment: Suggestion for adding header to requests? Chrome plugin or some such?

Answer (score 9):

No this is not possible. 
You have to conform to [Amazons Authentication API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/index.html?UsingBucket.html)

Check out some of the of wrappers listed [here](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/kbcategory.jspa?categoryID=47).

Comment: I don't think that article is claiming that you can use basic auth with S3.

Comment: See also http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#How_can_I_control_access_to_my_data_stored_on_Amazon_S3

Answer (score 9):

By now, this has become relatively straightforward on AWS. It's basically 3 things that need to be done:

1. Create a CloudFront function to add Basic Auth into the request.
2. Configure the Origin of the CloudFront distribution correctly in a few places.
3. Activate the CloudFront function.

That's it, no particular bells & whistles otherwise. Here's what I've done:

First, go to CloudFront, then click on Functions on the left, create a new function with a name of your choice (no region etc. necessary) and then add the following as the code of the function:

```js
function handler(event) {
  var user = "myuser";
  var pass = "mypassword";
  var requiredAuth = "Basic " + `${user}:${pass}`.toString('base64');

  var authHeader = event.request.headers.authorization;

  if (authHeader && authHeader.value === requiredAuth) {
    return event.request;
  } else {
    return {
      statusCode: 401,
      statusDescription: "Unauthorized",
      headers: {
        "www-authenticate": { value: 'Basic realm="Application"' },
      },
    };
  }
}
```

Then you can test with directly on the UI and assuming it works and assuming you have customized username and password, publish the function.

Next, open your CloudFront distribution and do the following:

1. Make sure your S3 bucket in the origin is configured as a REST endpoint and not a website endpoint, i.e. it must end on `.s3.amazonaws.com` and not have the word `website` in the hostname.
2. Also in the Origin settings, under "S3 bucket access", select "Yes use OAI (bucket can restrict access to only CloudFront)". In the setting below click on "Create OAI" to create a new OAI (unless you have an existing one and know what you're doing). And select "Yes, update the bucket policy" to allow AWS to add the necessary permissions to your OAI.
3. Finally, open your Behavior of the CloudFront distribution and scroll to the bottom. Under "Function associations", for "Viewer request" select "CloudFront Function" and select your newly created CloudFront function. Save your changes.

And that should be it. With a bit of luck a matter of a couple of minutes (realistically more, I know) and especially not additional complexity once this is all set up.

Comment: The Basic header is missing the required Realm. Some clients (Python urllib if I remember correctly) do not work without a Realm.  You can add one by changing the www-authenticate header value to something like `Basic realm="My Realm"`.

Comment: This is a fantastic solution with very few components. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Very spot on answers. Before I found this I had looked at many various blogs that talked about this, but did not explain it in such simple steps.

Comment: Here is the AWS documentation on this topic: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-overview.html

Answer (score 3):

I myself was trying to find solution to this problem. [This](https://medium.com/@lmakarov/serverless-password-protecting-a-static-website-in-an-aws-s3-bucket-bfaaa01b8666) post here has listed them all. Quoting the lines:

> I’ve been looking for months for a solution to add Basic HTTP Authentication to S3 buckets on Amazon. There are options involving pre-signed URLs (single object only), using a 3rd-party free or commercial service (privacy concerns), spinning up an EC2/Heroku/etc. with middleware to proxy requests (complicated and not serverless), using [page redirects and bucket policies](https://www.codeprocess.io/http-basic-authentication-with-s3-static-site-basic-idea/) (not secure).

**Bucket policies solution:**
I have personally tried this and it seems perfectly secure to me (unless you have a way to bypass aws bucket policies). It just requires s3 bucket to operate. Simple to implement. Basic idea:

1. Restrict access to the entire site, except allow public access to Entry File and Secret File.
2. Entry File *secure.html* that accepts an user input for the password and redirects to Secret File
3. Secret File *thisisasecret* that redirects to Main File (index.html) that hosts the real content of the site
4. Main File *main.html* that only allows access to requests originated from the same site.
5. All the other content like css, js files would be restricted by a bucket policy which will allow them served iff the request originated from your bucket URL.

**Using aws Lambda@Edge:** This solution require s3, aws lambda and aws cloudfront to operate. Basic idea:

1. Create a *secure.html*. Create text boxes to enter basic credentials from user here. This file should be publicly accessible and should call a lambda function.
2. While configuring cloudfront create a behaviour which says 'if you want to reach index.html, you need to do so via Signed URL'.
3. Just like above create a bucket policy to allow access to js, css, etc. files only when origin is your bucket URL.

Comment: i like to way you think

Answer (score 0):

I'm from AdroitLogic. About the linked article, it shows how the UltraESB could be placed between your client and Amazon S3 to authenticate your requests. If required, it could create a "proxy" service which will accept basic authentication from your client, and send the credentials the way Amazon S3 expects. This could be done in a trivial manner, and will hide any complexity for your client.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745831/list-all-objects-in-aws-s3-bucket/49100173#49100173) in this somewhat related question.

The question there was to get a bucket-object LIST without heavy S3 login authentication needed. So from your question, my answer does not really explain your inquiry for `Http-request with basic username/password authentication` - but rather gives a possibility to make the bucket private and still retrieve its data knowing an `identity-pool (ID)` and a `Amazon Resource Name (ARN)` (which you can consider similar to username and password). Of course, to get the (ID) and (ARN) you have to do some settings-work in the AWS main pages [as described in my 17-step answer here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745831/list-all-objects-in-aws-s3-bucket/49100173#49100173) - and also, it is not part of the GET-request but rather given within the AWSS3 framework that Amazon provides. I hope, it still gives you more options to your question ;)