# Basic HTTP Auth for AWS S3 hosted site, similar to .htaccess

Tags: html, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, http-authentication

I have a static HTML site hosted on Amazon S3.

Ideally I want to be able to limit access to a staging site in the same way as with a .htaccess/.htpasswd file.

I understand that bucket policies can be used to limit access (I have already used one to make the bucket contents publicly accessible), but I can't see any way to limit access.

In an ideal situation I would like an auth prompt - but appending a token to a URL would also work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Amazon S3 support HTTP request with basic authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091084/does-amazon-s3-support-http-request-with-basic-authentication)

Comment: I would take a look at the answer on this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/a/37553174/2398354

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible: checkout [s3auth](http://www.s3auth.com/) (no affiliation).

Answer (score 2):

I think the [AWS SDK for Javascript](http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/browser/) is what you're looking for. It allows you to login with Facebook, Google or Amazon.  Here's [another resource](https://medium.com/aws-activate-startup-blog/dynamic-websites-using-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript-in-the-browser-b3dd90c25b1e#.w9c1341es) using AWS login.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the standard AWS token keys for auth? You would need some JavaScript or similar to apply the key to all assets/internal links within the page which introduces a slight delay to loading but it should work in theory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try manipulating the AWS ACL, but otherwise, you will need to clone it to a repo on a private server or something.  From reading the description, it seems like S3's ability to serve static pages is pretty limited and is designed more as a convenience then a functional server.