# Restrict access to website hosted on S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I would like to host a static website at amazon S3, but I need to restrict access to it to certain users. This maybe by ip address or by amazon credentials (only logged in users can access the bucket's content.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes it indeed is possible. Better starting point for you would be read [S3 access control](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-access-control.html).

But by default the buckets created on S3 aren't public. So the default behaviour should be that it will only be accessible to person/program who/which has knowledge of your access and secret key.

You may also [edit bucket permission](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/EditingBucketPermissions.html) in order to give access to a particular AWS account or an email id.

In order to restrict access to certain IPs, you may create additional bucket policy.

**Restricting Access to Specific IP Addresses**

> This statement grants permissions to any user to perform any S3 action
>   on objects in the specified bucket. However, the request must
>   originate from the range of IP addresses specified in the condition.
>   The condition in this statement identifies 192.168.143.* range of
>   allowed IP addresses with one exception, 192.168.143.188.
>
> Note that the IPAddress and NotIpAddress values specified in the
>   condition uses CIDR notation described in RFC 2632. For more
>   information, go to http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4632.txt.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
            "Condition" : {
                "IpAddress" : {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "192.168.143.0/24" 
                },
                "NotIpAddress" : {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "192.168.143.188/32" 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    ]
}
```

For more, read [here](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_s3_a.html).

Comment: That IP address that you used in your example is within the private IPv4 network. Wouldn't that mean that anyone can access this bucket by just using that private IP address in my own network?

Comment: @justjulian - your IP would be NAT'ed to your public internet facing IP.

Comment: This response is useful to the extent that one restricts access to designated _public_ IP addresses (unlike the non-routable IP shown in the example policy).  As far as I understand it, S3-hosted static websites are served from an endpoint such as, say, `s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` which is public.  Hence this requires one to issue requests to said website via some public gateway and hence be seen by the AWS server as having the public IP supplied by the gateway, not one's private IP.  Catch 22...

Answer (score 15):

Edit: User/group based restrictions **[do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15291736/7190495) for static websites hosted in S3** since AWS is not registering your AWS Management Console (path: amazon.com) credentials/cookies for S3 (path: amazonaws.com) and not checking for them either.

Workaround: [www.s3auth.com](http://www.s3auth.com) - Basic Auth for S3 buckets might do the trick for you but involves a third party. Another solution may be [Query String Request Authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth), using an EC2 instance or the [Elastic Beanstalk Java SE Static Files Option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-platform.html#java-se-options). We are currently exploring securing our buckets with an [Amazon API Gateway as Amazon S3 Proxy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html).

---

Sidenote: There are some additional things to look out for, which are often not directly pointed out.

It is [currently not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30668874/7190495) in *bucket policies* to grant or restrict *group access*, only specific users. Since you also generally don't want to update each bucket policy for each change in your user structure and bucket policies might (unintentionally) interfere with your *user policies* you **may not want to use bucket policies**.

The user/group based policies only work with the `s3:GetBucketLocation` and `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` attached to `arn:aws:s3:::*` or `*` (unfortunately no filtering possible here, all bucket names will be visible for users/groups with this policy).

IAM Policy Example: (not a S3 Bucket Policy and **not** working for *Static Website Hosting*)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOURBUCKETNAME",
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOURBUCKETNAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

More detailed blog post: ["How to Restrict Amazon S3 Bucket Access to a Specific IAM Role"](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/)

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict access to the bucket/static website to certain http referers too. So you could set up a wordpress membership site where only logged in users to that site can access the site hosted on Amazon. E.g. mymembershipsite.com/members .

Comment: This answer definitely contributes, but I checked the docs to confirm my gut reaction: the client supplies the referrer, and therefore, like CORS, this only provides security to the client. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Condition

Answer (score 0):

You can put a Cloudfront in front of the S3 and an AWS WAF in front of the Cloudfront, whitelist only the IPs you want, and will work.