# Prevent users without an account to access website

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, web, amazon-s3

Apologies if this is a painfully obvious webdev question, but I'm new to the field and still trying to figure out the basics. I'm developing an S3 static website with AWS Cognito for user authentication. I have areas of the website that I only want registered users to be able to access, but I'm not sure how to begin limiting that.

I've looked into [limiting the content through CloudFront signed cookies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html), but the feature is relatively undocumented and I'm not sure if it's even what I want.

If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Your question is not at all obvious. There are many many ways to do these type of things, but this is too broad of a question for StackOverflow. You should just Google these concepts. Look at the documentation for the user authentication you have mentioned. Here's some info on how to ask questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the access in aws cognito authentication using role based tokens for each user, Read more on this [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html)

Answer (score 0):

IAM roles might prove beneficial for you. To delve deeper, go through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278698/restrict-access-to-website-hosted-on-s3)

This might prove helpful to you and broaden your horizon