# How can I update my AWS security group for my API so that it only allows inbound requests from my react web app hosted on netlify?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

I have been trying to update my security group on AWS such that it can only allow requests coming from my frontend react web app. but what i have tried is so far failing.

I have tried to `nslookup api.domain.tld` and use the IP listed there on my security group but that does not work. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: The request from your front-end comes from the IP address of the computer/network of the user of your web page.

Comment: @jarmod so that means, i cant use the ip a for the frontend domain in the sec group. then what can i use?

Comment: IP address allowlisting is not a strong security mechanism. It is better to use proper authentication e.g. via Cognito. Other ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278698/restrict-access-to-website-hosted-on-s3). If you know the IP addresses of all your users then you could add them to a Security Group but it's fragile, not scalable, and not 100% secure (because IP spoofing is s thing).

Comment: Apologies, the "other ideas here" link was for static S3 sites, which afaik is not what you're doing, so ignore that. Instead read [Control Access to Web Applications and Mobile Apps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/navigating-gdpr-compliance/control-access-to-web-applications-and-mobile-apps.html).