# Securing S3 website with username and password

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am working on a proof of concept static website and would like to use Amazon's S3 website hosting facility. I currently do not have a domain name but would like to secure the website with some form of username and password for access until we are ready.

I couldn't seem to find a quick and easy way to do this. I was thinking to use a NGINX docker image on my EC2 instance, use basic auth and serve the files from S3. Will this work or are there any other ways (lambda?) I can do this? Any pointers or example code would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can configure bucket policy and CORS to achieve that

Comment: This is possible using CloudFront and Lambda@Edge. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45971193/4550880

Comment: You star @LeonidMakarov, I'll give this a go 

Answer (score 1):

Better go Serverless with [Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/), since looks like you are sticking to the AWS stack. Going Serverless, you don't need pay for EC2 instances.