# Successful GET of a RESTful resource with Warning

Tags: rest

My REST service needs to return a warning along with an XML representation of the Resource on a GET invocation. Is there any way to represent the warning other than using a Wrapper XML Node to encapsulate the Resource and the Warning?

Comment: You could return a different 2xx HTTP status code.

Comment: Probably in a custom header, but http://stackoverflow.com/a/9169270/607033 ... So it might be better to use the response body, it depends on the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

It exists a dedicated header for warnings described in the [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.46):

> The Warning general-header field is used to carry additional information about the status or transformation of a message which might not be reflected in the message. This information is typically used to warn about a possible lack of semantic transparency from caching operations or transformations applied to the entity body of the message.

Something like that:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Warning: 299 ServiceName "Invalid input error: X is unrecognized parameter name."
```

According to your use case, it's something you could consider...

The only other place I see is the response payload...

Hope it helps you,
Thierry