# Authentication With Imgur API

Tags: python, api, imgur

So I'm writing a simple-ish script that can automatically download images from Imgur. I've come across the Imgur API but am struggling to get it to work. I registered an app but am not sure how to use it to be able to get information about images or albums. I do not want to be able to log in as a user or anything like that - just provide a URL of an album or a single image and be able to download it.

I've read that if I want to do this then I don't need to use the oauth stuff, I should just be able to use a client ID.

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/2uzxfv/how_do_i_get_fully_authenticated_to_use_imgurs_api/

The script I am writing is using Python, but just to test out the API I am typing the URL into the browser. If I go to the following URL:

https://api.imgur.com/3/album/qTt8G?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID

Then I receive the following response:

> {"data":{"error":"Authentication
>   required","request":"/3/album/qTt8G","method":"GET"},"success":false,"status":401}

The full album URL is https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKvbU.jpg
I've tried reading through the API docs, but am stuck with this.

Useful info:

https://api.imgur.com/oauth2

https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/album

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just used the Imgur API helper that is available on Github to do all the work. Just needed to provide the client ID and secret.

https://github.com/Imgur/imgurpython

Comment: The Python library is no longer supported though :-(

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide the client-id in the header of the GET request. You are sending it using query parameters. [HTTP Headers vs query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169081/rest-apis-custom-http-headers-vs-url-parameters)

You can use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) for this. 
In Python code, you can use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.imgur.com/3/album/{{albumHash}}"

headers = {'Authorization': 'Client-ID {{clientId}}'}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Check out imgur api [docs](https://apidocs.imgur.com/)  for more.