# Which is more secure GET or POST sending parameters with cURL at PHP

Tags: php, security, curl, protocols

I want to connect in a secure way with an API and I am using `cURL` to do it using HTTPS and SSL.

Now, i was wondering what is better in terms of security, sending the data through `GET` or `POST`:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://api.website.com/connect.php?user=xxx&pass=xxxx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Or

```
$param['user'] = 'xxxx';
$param['pass'] = 'xxxx';
$ch = curl_init("http://api.website.com/connect.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $Parameters);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I also realized that `POST` is much more slower retrieving the data.

Comment: You should really be asking what the page you're curling requires

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither. "GET parameters" are part of the URL which is part of the HTTP request header, "POST parameters" are part of the HTTP request body. Both are part of the same HTTP request, which is all just plain text. There's no difference in "security".

Use GET or POST semantically depending on the kind of request, not because of security concerns.

The only thing is that the requested URLs are more likely to appear in log files than the entire request body. But the one logging would be the service you send the data to anyway, so it doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: Right. Encryption brings security, not the format you're sending the data in over an unencrypted connection.

Comment: "... the one logging would be the service you send the data to anyway, so it doesn't make much of a difference." - well, we now know that's not the case :)

Answer (score 1):

None of them is secure, but if you use a secure connection (https) you can use POST, asthe body will get encrypted. It is not a good idea to send passwords, not even usernames with the URI.

Comment: HTTP headers are encrypted as well over HTTPS.

Comment: @deceze I didn't say they were not, but as you said, the POST goes in the body, so I didn't mention the headers. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187655/are-https-headers-encrypted)

Comment: Then I'm not sure why you recommend POST over GET "asthe body will get encrypted"...?!

Comment: I'm not downvoting but this isn't a very good answer because it suggests that POST data is encrypted but the querystring is not and therefore post data is more secure, which is incorrect. With `https` the entire request is encrypted so in terms of security, GET or POST makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

In this cause because you are using HTTPS, GET and POST as just as secure as eachother because both of which will be encrypted on the transport layer.

If for example you weren't using HTTPS then in some cases, POST can be *better* but not necessarily more *secure*. This is because servers typically log the querystring whereas POST data isn't typically logged.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Btw, should i add the `https` at my connect URL to make it secure?

Comment: @Steve yes if the external server supports https :)