# Encrypting Amazon S3 URL over the network to secure data access

Tags: security, encryption, https, amazon-s3, man-in-the-middle

I want to host copyrighted data on a Amazon S3 bucket (to have a larger bandwidth available than what my servers can handle) and provide access to these copyrighted data for a large numbers of authorized clients.

My problem is:

- i create signed expiring HTTPS URL for these resources on the server side
- these URL are sent to clients via a HTTPS connection
- when the client uses these URL to download the contents, the URL can be seen in clear for any man-in-the-middle

In details, the URL are created via a Ruby On Rails server using the fog gem. 
The mobile clients I'm talking about are iOS devices.
The proxy I've used for my test is mitmproxy.

The URL I generated looked like this:

> https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myFileKey?AWSAccessKeyId=AAA&Signature=BBB&Expires=CCC

I'm not a network or security expert but I had found resources stating nothing was going clear over HTTPS connections (for instance, cf. [Are HTTPS headers encrypted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187655/are-https-headers-encrypted)). Is it a misconfiguration of my test that led to this clear URL? Any tip on what could have gone wrong here? Is there a real chance I can prevent S3 URL to go clear over the network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So firstly, when sending a request over SSL all parameters are encrypted. If you were to look at the traffic going through a normal proxy you wouldn't be able to read them.

However, many proxies allow interception of SSL data by creating dummy certificates. This is exactly what *mitmproxy* does. You may well have enabled this and not realised it (although you would have had to install a client-side certificate to do this).

The bottom line is that your AWS URLs could be easily intercepted by somebody looking to reverse engineer your app, either through a proxy or by tapping into the binary itself. However, this isn't a 'bad thing' per se: Amazon themselves know this happens, and that's why they're not sending the secret key directly in the URL itself, but using a signature.

I don't think this is a huge problem for you: after all, you're creating URLs that expire, so even if someone *can* get hold of them through a proxy they'll only be able to access the URL for as long as it is valid. To access your resources post-expiry would require direct access to your secret key. Now, it actually turns out this isn't *impossible* (since you've probably hard-coded it into your binary), but it's difficult enough that most users won't be bothering with it.

I'd encourage you to be realistic with your security and copyright prevention: when you've got client-side native code it's not a matter of *if* it gets broken but *when*.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I remembered installing a dummy certificate for mitmproxy one year ago. Thanks for your answer.