# Securing API with access token

Tags: api, http, api-design

I am not using any kind of SSL and I am wondering the following:

If I have a list of api keys stored in my DB, and I force users who want to consume the API to do the calls with the following HTTP Header:

```
'Authorization: Token token="c576f0136149a2e2d9127b3901015545"'
```

And then I check if that token exists.  Is it secure to put that in the HTTP header? If not, how could I secure it?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone in the middle will be able to read the token. For something serious SSL would be a must, I guess.

Comment: So, SSL would encrypt the headers too?

Comment: Without SSL, it'd be comparatively very hard to secure.

Comment: @HommerSmith Yes, SSL encrypts all data you're communicating over that connection, including the headers.

Comment: @HommerSmith: Yes, See also: [Are HTTPS headers encrypted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187655/are-https-headers-encrypted)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is absolutely not secure. It suffers from Man-in-the-Middle and replay attacks.

Putting access control mechanisms in HTTP headers is awful because HTTP **has no security**. That means all data, including passwords, headers, etc. is transmitted **in the clear**.

When you use SSL, your HTTP request is tunnelled through a secure connection (why it is secure isn't too important here, just assume it is).

Only then, having ensured the whole HTTP communication is secure by tunnelling it through a secure SSL tunnel, can you safely put access control mechanisms in the header. Although if you are using SSL tunnelling then really it doesn't matter where you put the token.