# Java servlet: do parameters sent with doGet() get encoded using HTTPS?

Tags: java, servlets

If I have a java servlet using `doGet()` such as:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
...
param1 = request.getParameter("param1");
...
```

and it gets accessed by calling `https://www.mydomain.com/MyServlet?param1=hello`.

Is `param1` secure since I'm using https (that is, `param1` is not visible to anyone but the user accessing the link)? Or, is it visible because `doGet()` places param1 in the HTML header? If the latter, what's equivalent `doPost()` look like here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are HTTPS headers encrypted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187655/are-https-headers-encrypted)

Comment: it depends on if the link originated in the https site or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the link originates in the https site, then its fine.

If the link does not originate in the https site, its not. Like if you literally put that link on another site, or same site using http.  So if you had `http://www.example.com/` and it linked to `https://www.example.com/MyServlet?param1=hello` then it wouldn't actually be secure because you printed out the link over plain text.

Comment: thanks @developerwjk, what if I sent the link `https://www...` in an email and the user clicked the link from there?

Comment: @user46688, The email is probably sent plaintext, which means anyone who can intercept the email can see what that parameter is.