# Routing of an encrypted https packet

Tags: tcp, https

Reference to this question linked
[Are HTTPS headers encrypted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187655/are-https-headers-encrypted)

As per the answer, if all of  the HTTPS packet is encrypted, then how would it be routed at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packet routing does not happen at the http layer. The routing happens at lower layers, ie IP. HTTPS is http encrypted by ssl. for ip or tcp, it is just some payload. even if you send http packet, these layers would not look into them. OSI model is a good reference for further clarifications.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But my question is the TCP/IP packet finally leaving the host resulted by a SSL session fully encrypted? if so it is, how does it get routed? As I know, destination and source address are placed in the header of the packet. Should the packet be encrypted they too will need to be.

Comment: The ssl session is over the tcp/ip, so for the tcp session the ssl encrypted packet is pay load, the tcp/ip headers are not encrypted.

Comment: The ordet of packet is somewhat like this; mac/ethernet header, ip header, tcp header, http(s) header. here if https, the http header and its payload is encrypted, the first 3 headers are intact.