# How to handle the JWT on the client layer?

Tags: javascript, security, client, jwt

This is a subjective question, although I believe this is not opinion based. The only reason of asking it here is that I could not find satisfying answer even after reading multiple articles on JWT Authentication.

I recently started learning JWT and found that it is a 3 part token issued by server to client for authenticity along with passing data like user-scope/roles/permission etc in forms of claims.

My question however are:

1. The claim part of token still is base64 encoded string which can easily be parsed using `atob/btoa`. So is the transmission really secure ? What is the real gain here ?
2. There are multiple articles on generating and sending token to UI. However, almost no good articles on what UI does exactly with it. Is it a common practice to decode the token using `atob` and use the content within it ? Or is there a different way of validating and retrieving data from it.
3. Is it really secure to transmit data via headers. I mean is it safe against things like MITM, XSS etc.

I would really appreciate some efforts from the expert in resolving these queries ?

Answer (score 0):

For question #1, the gain is *not* on the client side.  If you can't trust what you received from the server, you can't trust it no matter how it's obfuscated/encoded/encrypted/.  The point is that you send this token *back* to the server.  On the server, a quick check will tell that this token is legitimate.  Imagine a complex login scenario, where MegaCorp looks up permissions for the user across 739 subsystems, combines them into a single payload, and then doesn't have to do that again on further requests.  When the client sends the token back, it validates that you are properly logged in and uses the permissions to do further processing.

For #2, you can put whatever you like into this payload, so long as it isn't meant to be too secure.  I mostly use it for basic user info and for application permissions.  So I can paint the user's name and offer a link to the specific user settings page.  I can check whether the user has access to an administrative page or whatever permissions I need to check.  While a malicious user can fool the system by manipulating that data client-side, and can therefore, say, see the admin page, when the call goes back to the server to get the data for that page, the token is either illegitimate and the request will be rejected, or it won't contain the proper permissions and, again, it will be rejected.

I don't really know enough about security to attempt an answer to #3.

---

Some people use JWT only for `isLoggedIn`, which is fine, but I think misses some useful possibilities.  Used properly, this can be the single mechanism to capture user information for both the client and the server.  But the important side to my mind is the server.  This can be done in many ways on the client.  But it's hard to find something better for the server.

Answer (score 0):

> The claim part of token still is base64 encoded string which can
>   easily be parsed using atob/btoa. So is the transmission really secure
>   ? What is the real gain here ?

The transmission is secure (cannot be read/modified by others) if you send the token via https. JWT contains 2 important parts: a payload and a verify signature.
The signature can be produced and verified only by one person and prove that the payload is legit for that person.
Here is a simple use case:

1. Client send is credential to the Auth server to receive the right to publish something
2. The server receives the credential and valid them through a complex process then send back to the client a JWT saying: {I give Client the right to publish signed the Auths erver}
3. The Client store locally the token
4. When the client needs to publish something he sends the JWT and is work to server B which share the signing key with Auth server.
5. Server B verify easily the token and publish the work of the client

Another example of usage is authentication via mail only.

> There are multiple articles on generating and sending token to UI.
>   However, almost no good articles on what UI does exactly with it. Is
>   it a common practice to decode the token using atob and use the
>   content within it ? Or is there a different way of validating and
>   retrieving data from it.

In general, the client wants to obtain a token from some server to send it back later. The client cannot verify the signature because he does not share the private key with the server, he is not a source of trust.

> Is it really secure to transmit data via headers. I mean is it safe
>   against things like MITM, XSS etc.

Using https it is safe: [Are HTTPS headers encrypted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187655/are-https-headers-encrypted)