# Authorization request header Vs POST request body for credentials

Tags: authentication

Which is the right approach to send user credentials from the front end to the backend server?
I see examples where some developers use the authorization headers and some pass the credentials in the POST body.

Comment: There is no right or wrong here - it highly depends on the standard you're going to implement. For example in OAuth2, the header is used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Credentials usually go to the request body once, when trying log in.
You should receive a token in return, although whether you send this token via HTTP header, request body or as a GET param is up to you ( or the protocol you are implementing ).

It's generally a good practice to use the header, because GET requests shouldn't include request body and passing the token as a GET parameter may not always be an option ( e.g. due to the token appearing in various logs ).

Either way, I would advise you to avoid trying to implement your own protocol and use an existing standard instead.

Comment: To be clear, passing secret information as a URL parameter in a GET request is unsafe, even with HTTPS/SSL.

Answer (score 6):

The only safe method for a website to transfer a password to the server is using HTTPS/SSL. If the connection itself is not encrypted, a ManInTheMiddle can modify or strip away any JavaScript sent to the client. So you cannot rely on client-side hashing.

Moreover always use headers for sending sensitive data like USER-ID, API-KEY, AUTH-TOKENS
You can refer to this stack question also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187655/are-https-headers-encrypted) for more information and this [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/113393/how-to-securely-transfer-password-from-a-registration-page-to-the-database)

Comment: Thank you for the links

Comment: @unnik Thank you