# JWT Token Verification to decode and Protect Routes in MEAN App

Tags: node.js, angular, express, authentication, jwt

I am trying to authenticate users using JWT. I am assigning a token on login.

```
if (client) {
      // Check if Client does exist, then compare password provided by Client
      if (!req.body.password) {
        res.json({ success: false, message: "No password provided" }); // Password was not provided
      } else {
        var validPassword = client.password === req.body.password; // Check if password matches password provided by Client
        if (!validPassword) {
          res.json({ success: false, message: {password: {message: "Incorrect Password"}} }); // Password does not match password in database
        } else {
          if (!client.active) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: {active: {message: "Account is not activated"}} }); // Account is not activated
          } else {
            var token = jwt.sign(
              { username: client.username, email: client.email },
              secret,
              { expiresIn: "24h" }
            ); // Logged in: Give Client token
            res.json({
              success: true,
              message: "Client authenticated!",
              token: token
            }); // Return token in JSON object to controller
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

After login, I am checking the token in requests made my the user.

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {   
var token = req.body.token || req.body.query || req.headers['x-access-token']; // Check for token in body, URL, or headers
// Check if token is valid and not expired  
if (token) {
// Function to verify token
    jwt.verify(token, secret, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Token invalid' }); // Token has expired or is invalid
        } else {
            req.decoded = decoded; // Assign to req. variable to be able to use it in next() route ('/me' route)
            next(); // Required to leave middleware
        }
    });
} else {
    res.json({ success: false, message: 'No token provided' }); // Return error if no token was provided in the request
}
```

});

I am putting all the protected routes after the check token. Users can access the profile page /me

```
router.post('/me', function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.decoded); // Return the token acquired from middleware
});
```

How can I check the token in req.body in Angular 11? I have tried to setToken using localStorage but it seems I am not doing it correctly.

```
localStorage.setItem('userToken', response.token);
```

It seems to be working fine in Postman when accessing the /me route by passing the token in body. It shows whether the token found or not. If found then it shows the result

{
"email": "example@gmail.com",
"iat": 1634704834,
"exp": 1634791234
}

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine. I think, you just need to implement an interceptor on the frontend side. It will pick the auth token from the local storage, and attach it with all the requests.

Sample code

```
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './service/auth.module';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let loggedInUser = this.authService.currentUserValue;
        token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(user.token));
        if (token) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            });
        }

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

And yeah, sending authentication token in the body params is not considered a good practice. Safe method is to use headers always for such sensitive information. More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53515942/authorization-request-header-vs-post-request-body-for-credentials)