# Is the headers in an HTTPS request encrypted?

Tags: web, encryption, https, tcp, ip

I am unsure if the headers in the are meant to be encrypted as I keep getting mixed answers?

I have read online that participants of an HTTPS interaction are not fully preserved as there are headers containing the sender and receiver adresses in the IP datagram. And from what I know, HTTPS uses TLS to encrypt data.

And in a few other stackoverflow questions such as this state that they are encrypted

[Are HTTPS headers encrypted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187655/are-https-headers-encrypted)

I am very confused on what is correct

Comment: The question was asked and answered in the linked question you referenced, so I'm voting to close as a duplicate. What possible benefit could an answer that simply repeats another answer be?

Comment: *"I have read online that participants of an HTTPS interaction are not fully preserved as there are headers containing the sender and receiver adresses in the IP datagram."* - sender and receiver address are not part of the HTTP header. They are part of the the network layer and they are needed in clear to deliver the request to the right target and to get the response back to the right sender. Note that HTTPS provides protection against sniffing and manipulation, not anonymity.